# Define a variable of different types

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, vb.net, generics

i wonder if it's possible to define a variable/property of more than one type.

Let's say i want a property `TextWebControl` that is a `WebControl`  and also implements `Web.UI.ITextControl`(f.e. like a TextBox or Label). But i don't want to enforce that it is a TextBox or Label, but only one that inherits from WebControl and also implements ITextControl so that it also would work with controls added in future releases of .Net-Framework.

- .Net-Framework 4.0

**Edit**: I have retagged the question and added VB.Net because it's my default language. Normally it's no problem for me to understand C# also, but i must admit that it's difficult to translate generic stuff to VB.Net without experiences and it's also better documentated in C# than in VB. So i would appreciate(and aceept) a working example of a VB.net generic type of ITextControl/WebControl.

From Marc's answer i understand that i need a generic class. But how do i instantiate it in `SomeClass`? This won't compile:

```
Class SomeClass
   Public Property info As InfoControl(Of WebControl, ITextControl)
End Class

Public Class InfoControl(Of T As {WebControl, ITextControl})
End Class
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Properties cannot be generic...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only inside generics, i.e.

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T whatever) where T : WebControl, ITextControl {...}
```

Otherwise, you are going to have to pick between them, or have 2 variables.

Comment: can you please provide some example for better understanding

Comment: thank you. I have edited my question. Unfortuately on generics i'm unable to translate it to my default language VB.Net, so can you(or somebody else) provide an example in VB.

Comment: @Tim me neither ;p I'm afraid VB is mainly "read only" for me now... but I suspect you are simply going to have to settle for one or the other type, or two variables.

Comment: The Vb.Net version of that code is `Sub SomeMethod(Of T As {WebControl, ITextControl})() ... End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

I would say either you define your variable of a certain interface, or you use the lowest possible base class derived by all classes you think you would need to support.

Comment: So i must  use WebControl as Baseclass and hope that the WebControl given implements ITextControl? That seems to be not-so-clean, i hoped generics would be made for this. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the VB version of a generic class with multiple constraints:

```
Public Class SomeClass(Of T As {WebControl, ITextControl})
    Private _item As T
    Public Property Item() As T
        Get
            Return Me._item
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As T)
            Me.ParseValue(value)
            Me._item = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub ParseValue(ByVal value As T)
        ''//do something with value here if you want
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal item As T)
        Me._item = item
    End Sub
End Class
```

And to instantiate it you'd do this:

```
    Dim L As New Label()
    Dim S1 As New SomeClass(Of Label)(L)
```